# How can i backup couchdb data?

Tags: docker, couchdb, backup

I am trying to backup my data stored in couchdb with the following command:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from couchdb -v $(pwd):/backup couchdb tar cvf /backup/backup.tar opt/couchdb/
```

Restore:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from couchdb -v $(pwd):/backup couchdb bash -c "bash && cd opt/ && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  fastapi:
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: fastapi
    volumes:
      - fastapi_data:/code/app/storage
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - api
  db:
    image: couchdb:3
    container_name: couchdb
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=couchdb
    volumes:
      - couchdb_data:/tmp
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - api

volumes:
  couchdb_data:
    driver: local
  fastapi_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  api:
    driver: bridge
```

But my backup don't work. Now i think my bnackup script is incorrect.

Does anyone know the best way to backup Volumes Data from Docker or can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!